# Run Script on multiple sheets in the same spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a running script that updates the D:N column with current months. It does currently only update the ActiveSheet, I would like to refactor it so it runs on all 4 sheets in the spreadsheet. 
[image]

**Current Code:**

```
function setDates(){
  var monthNames = ["Jan (Qty)", "Feb (Qty)", "Mar (Qty)",
                    "Apr (Qty)", "May (Qty)", "Jun (Qty)",
                    "Jul (Qty)", "Aug (Qty)", "Sep (Qty)",
                    "Oct (Qty)", "Nov (Qty)", "Dec (Qty)"];

  var currentMonths = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("D1:N1").getValues()[0];
  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();

  if (currentMonths[0] == monthNames[currentMonth]){return;}

  for (var col = 0; col < currentMonths.length; col++){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                  .getActiveSheet()
                  .getRange(1,4+col)
                  .setValue(monthNames[(currentMonth + col > 11 ?
                                        currentMonth + col - 12 :
                                        currentMonth + col)]);
  }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

```
function sheetNamesFunction(){
            var sheets = ['Sheet1',
                          'Sheet2',
                          'Sheet3',
                          'Sheet4']; 
            for (var s in sheets){
          setDates(sheets[s]);
            }
          }


 function setDates(sheetName){
  var monthNames = ["Jan (Qty)", "Feb (Qty)", "Mar (Qty)",
                    "Apr (Qty)", "May (Qty)", "Jun (Qty)",
                    "Jul (Qty)", "Aug (Qty)", "Sep (Qty)",
                    "Oct (Qty)", "Nov (Qty)", "Dec (Qty)"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ed_x52cQx5A0RSqwxsB925wzbGt5kh0Gsi0ybl');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var currentMonths = sh.getRange("D1:N1").getValues()[0];

  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  if (currentMonths[0] == monthNames[currentMonth]){return;}

  for (var col = 0; col < currentMonths.length; col++){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1,4+col)
    .setValue(monthNames[(currentMonth + col > 11 ?
                          currentMonth + col - 12 :
                          currentMonth + col)]);
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the following:
[image]

If I run log on

```
var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
      Logger.log(sh);
```

I can see that the first value is "null":
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a sheet named EXACTLY `Sheet1`, then the `null` result is expected. (Have you checked that name? Is there an extra space, maybe?)

It's not the best form to use the `for..in` construct with arrays, instead you should use a standard `for` loop. Personally, I find it helps me differentiate between arrays and objects ("associative arrays"). You might want to read: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

You can avoid the problem by changing your approach a bit.
Instead of dealing with sheet names, you can use Sheet Objects.

```js
function setDatesOnAllSheets(){
  //  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ed_x52cQx5A0RSqwxsB925wzbGt5kh0Gsi0ybl');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var s=0; s<sheets.length; s++) {
     setDates(sheets[s]);
  }
}


function setDates(sheet){
  var monthNames = ["Jan (Qty)", "Feb (Qty)", "Mar (Qty)",
                    "Apr (Qty)", "May (Qty)", "Jun (Qty)",
                    "Jul (Qty)", "Aug (Qty)", "Sep (Qty)",
                    "Oct (Qty)", "Nov (Qty)", "Dec (Qty)"];

  var currentMonths = sh.getRange("D1:N1").getValues()[0];

  var currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
  if (currentMonths[0] == monthNames[currentMonth]){return;}

  for (var col = 0; col < currentMonths.length; col++){
    sheet
    .getRange(1,4+col)
    .setValue(monthNames[(currentMonth + col > 11 ?
                          currentMonth + col - 12 :
                          currentMonth + col)]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Mogsdad you are a fuc*ing **GOD** ! That worked, i just needed to change sh.getRange to sheet.getRange. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same issue with my script and this array notation solved it: `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0,1];` whereas before I had `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");`  The array notation `[0,1]` with the `.getSheets()[0,1]` action gets sheets 0 and 1 (in my case Sheet1 and Sheet2) because arrays begin from zero, not from one.  Hope that can help new viewers!